# Can anyone help me create a junit test case for this class?

Tags: java, junit

I created a Factory pattern program which assigns a random policy to an MP.  the random number generator generates numbers between 1-3 inclusive and this program uses the random number to call the appropriate policy from the Policy class. 
Could anyone please help me to create a Junit test case for this class? Thanks in advance.

```
public class PolicyFactory {
    public Policy createPolicy(int num) {
            Policy policy = null;

        if(num==1) {
            policy = new Policy1();
        } else if(num==2) {
            policy = new Policy2();
        } else if(num==3) {
            policy = new Policy3();
        }

        return policy;
    }

}
```

Comment: I would suggest 4 unit tests.

Comment: public void testPf() {
  Junit test = new Junit ();
  int result = test.createPolicy(1,2,3);
  assertEquals(1 || 2 || 3 , result);
 }

Comment: My main struggle I'm having is being able to test that any number between 1-3 can be passed through the method, and the appropriate method must be output. I've never done Junit testing before so that is why my attempt is quite poor.

Answer (score 1):

In your case the random number is generated outside the method and passed into it. That makes unit testing very easy: just test all cases:

```
assertEquals("Policy 1 created", Policy1.class, createPolicy(1).getClass());
```

And so on.

More complex is when the random number is generated inside the method itself. In that case you would need to mock generating random numbers with specific values to test all cases. There are good tools such as Mockito and Easymock to do this.

Comment: After implementing this line I have received an error asking me to create this method, however I have this method declared as "public Policy createPolicy(int num)" within another class, have I declared it wrong somehow?

Comment: @TashaCampbell the answer treats the method as `static`. You'll need either to declare the method as `static`, or create an instance of `PolicyFactory` for the test.

Comment: Yea I had tried declaring it static and it makes no difference at all.

Comment: @TashaCampbell even then, you would need either a static import, or to invoke it as `PolicyFactory.createPolicy(1)` rather than just `createPolicy(1)`.

Comment: That seems to have got rid of my errors, however, my junit test has failed, any ideas?

Comment: what does your test looks like?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for something like this:

```
@Test
public void testPf() {
    Assert.assertTrue(policyFactoryInstance.createPolicy(1) instance of Policy1)
    Assert.assertTrue(policyFactoryInstance.createPolicy(2) instance of Policy2)
    Assert.assertTrue(policyFactoryInstance.createPolicy(3) instance of Policy3)
    Assert.assertNull(policyFactoryInstance.createPolicy(0))
}
```

Comment: Also test that createPolicy(n), where n is not 1, 2 or 3, returns null.